# Finding the cost

Tags: calculus

> Anwar would have to incur Rs 600, Rs 900 and Rs 1200 as the expenses if he got a job done by A,B and C respectively. The daily wages of A, B and C are Rs 100, Rs 60 and Rs 40 respectively. Find the cost of Anwar of getting the job done by all three of them (in Rs)?
>
> (A) 600
>
> (B) 700
>
> (C) 750
>
> (D) 800

I have totally no clue of this question. Any help will be appropriated.

Comment: Are your sure your excercise is *exactly* stated that way? Or is more like: if he got a job done by either A,B or C (only by one of them?)

Comment: @Bernd Updated, not changed so much though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Then you probably have to think this way: It takes A 6 days, B 15 days, C 30 days to get the job done by himself. So now you have to figure out, how long it takes, if they do the job together, multiply that with their daily wage and add up.

Hint: Solve the equation

d/6 +d/15 + d/30 = 1

d should then be the number of days needed, when they work on it together

Comment: Does this help you? Do you understand it? Any further questions?

Comment: Is `expenses` the same to `wages`? It seems you treat them the same.

Comment: Well I understand it that way (The expenses are the wages for the persons doing it). Solution gives d = 3,75 and therefore wages 3,75 * 100 + 3,75 * 60 + 3,75 * 40 = 750